# When generating random CGFloat numbers in range, cuts to 1 decimal place

Tags: swift, range, between, arc4random

I found two formulas to generate random numbers between two numbers in Swift.  The first (most common) is:

```
let randomNum = CGFloat((arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upperNum-lowerNum)) )+ CGFloat(UInt32(lowerNum)))` which gives a number as X.0 as a solution (random whole number)
```

To get full CGFloat value of X.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, this works:

```
let randomNum = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(lowerNum - upperNum) + min(lowerNum, upperNum)
```

why does the first one truncate to whole number?

Comment: The first one doesn't truncate anything. The entire formula is working only with integers.

Comment: Ah yes... so even if I cast to CGFloat the UIInt32 keeps as Integer?        What in the second formula allows full float?

Comment: Casting any number to `UInt32` gives you an integer. In the second, you are working with floating point values.

Comment: OK, got it.  Thanks again ready!